# Python using def function to create defferent variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I'm new to python and just want to ask if it is possible to use def function to create new variables.

Here is my code, trying to build a function that i can input the variable name and data, it will automaticed output the different list. But it seems not working:

```
def Length5_list(list_name, a, b, c, d, e):
    list_name = list()
    list_name = [a, b, c, d, e]

list_name1 = 'first_list'
list_name2 = 'second_list'
A = 1
B = 2
C = 3
D = 4
E = 5

Length5_list(list_name1, A, B, C, D, E)
Length5_list(list_name2, E, D, C, B, A)

print(list_name1, list_name2)
```

Also wondering if there is any other way to achieve it?

Thank you guys soooo much!

Comment: Don't use dynamic variable names. It's almost always a poor design choice.

Answer (score 1):

Do not name variables dynamically. Instead, use a dictionary and update it with items. Then retrieve your lists via `d[key]`, where `key` is a string you have supplied to your function.

Here's an example:

```
def lister(list_name, a, b, c, d, e):
    return {list_name: [a, b, c, d, e]}

list_name1 = 'first_list'
list_name2 = 'second_list'
A, B, C, D, E = range(1, 6)

d = {}

d.update(lister(list_name1, A, B, C, D, E))
d.update(lister(list_name2, E, D, C, B, A))

print(d['first_list'], d['second_list'], sep='\n')

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

While there may be ways to create variables dynamically, it is not recommended. See [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables) for more details.